# Stack won't store value in C

Tags: c, stack

I'm currently trying to make a simple Stack menu program that will push and pop values that the user inputs. (and also print out the stack.)

This is the code I have so far. When I try to insert a value(case 1) I think it works- but I'm not sure since when I try to print out the stack(case 3) it always says "Stack is Empty!". And when I try to pop the stack(case 2) it just crashes.

I don't know if one of my structures are off, or if my pointers just aren't right.

Thank you for your help in advance, and I'm very sorry for the messy code- I'm still very new to this!

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#define EMPTY 0

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};
typedef struct node Stack;

Stack* get_node()
{
    Stack *tmp;
    tmp = (Stack*) malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    tmp->link = EMPTY;
    return tmp;
}

void push(Stack **top, int data)
{
    Stack *tmp;
    tmp = *top;

    *top = get_node();

    (*top)->data = data;
    (*top)->link = tmp;
}

void pop(Stack **top)
{
    Stack *tmp;
    int num;
    if (top == EMPTY)
    {
        printf("Stack is Empty!");
    }
    else
    {
        tmp = *top;
        printf("%d", tmp->data);
        *top = tmp->link;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

void stack(Stack *top)
{
    if (top == EMPTY)
    {
        printf("Stack is Empty...");
    }
    else
    {
        Stack *tmp = top;
        while (tmp->link != EMPTY)
        {
            printf("%d", tmp->data);
            tmp = tmp->link;
        }
    }
}

void menu(int choice)
{
    Stack *top = EMPTY;
    int data;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter Data : ");
            scanf_s("%d", &data);
            push(&top, data);
            break;

        case 2:
            pop(&top);
            break;

        case 3:
            stack(top);
            break;

        case 4:
            exit(1);
    }
}

void main()
{
    int choice;

    printf("< < = M e n u = = >\n");
    printf("1.push\n");
    printf("2.pop\n");
    printf("3.print_all\n");
    printf("4.quit\n");
    printf("Select : ");
    while (1)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &choice);
        menu(choice);
    }
}
```

Comment: "what's wrong with my code": that's a very bad way to phrase your question.

Comment: Oh I am very sorry, this is the first time I'm using this site and I don't know how to make a good title. What should I edit it to?

Comment: you should narrow the problem down to a [mcve]. Then you'll know what title to change to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some small changes like make `top` `pointer` as a `static` in `menu()` function because  if you will not make it  as a `static` , it gets every time  initialized with `zero`.
Replace this

```
Stack *top = EMPTY;
```

with

```
  static Stack *top ;
```

and modify the `stack()` function, you are printing one less elements as

```
void stack(Stack *top)
{
    if (top == EMPTY)
    {
        printf("Stack is Empty...");
    }
    else
    {
        Stack *tmp = top;
        while (tmp != EMPTY) // here you wrote as tmp->link
        {
            printf("%d \n ", tmp->data);
            tmp = tmp->link;
        }
    }
}
```

remaining all your logic is correct. I hope  it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually keeping the stack anywhere. Everytime you enter a option into the menu, the `menu` function starts with an empty `Stack`. When you insert, and then print out the `Stack` it will have an empty `Stack` each time.

```
void menu(int choice)
{
    Stack *top = EMPTY; // Problem -  Always empty Stack for each call
    int data;
    ...
}
```

To fix this, you need to either have a global variable `Stack` or pass the `Stack` to every function for use.